# How to remove all trees in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm looking to remove all the trees in my creative Bedrock world. Is there a command to do so? If there is, what is it?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I answered the best I could with the title and all but im pretty sure this is where someone with higher rep or something would say to clarify your question. I'm not entirely sure but it might help get a more specific answer!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a command to remove all trees, especially in bedrock edition.

As far as I know the only way to remove trees at all without the use of mods would be to use a superflat world which can be selected before you make the world, and as the name implies, it makes the world entirely flat (except for villages unless structures are turned off as well).